# Maven Dependencies - Complete Removal

Tags: maven

If I want to remove all the dependencies in maven and want a fresh start, how will I do that?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to do? Which problem do you want to solve? Do you want to remove dependencies from the POM? From the local repository? From where?

Comment: I want to remove dependencies from POM and local repository  as well. I want to know about both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Call `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -reResolve=false` to delete the dependencies from the local repository.
2. Go to your `pom.xml` and remove the content of `<dependencies>`. This will remove all dependencies from your POM (except those, that may have been defined in a Parent POM).